# How to update lookup field of CRM entity using Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, azure-logic-apps

I am currently writing an Azure app which is expected to update records in CRM. I am successfully able to update normal fields, but updating of lookup field is not working.
It gives an error saying -

> Property lookupfieldid_value cannot be updated to null. The reference
>   property can only be deleted.

I am supplying the values in the designer, but when I look at the code view it always shows "lookupfieldid" as null, whereas "lookupfieldid_value" contains the value which I have supplied.

Anyone having an idea of how to pass lookup field value to update CRM records using Logic App?

Comment: How are you communicating with CRM? Are you using the XRM client or REST api?

Comment: Even though this is not the real answer it can guide you to a right direction https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/10252870-00fc-4f60-862c-539f0fa01c62/dynamics-365-managed-api-optionset-validationparsing?forum=azurelogicapps